# Issue with turning a button into a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I want to have an edit button which turns into a textarea when clicked.  However, when I do click the button, the resulting textarea will not hold keyboard focus and I cannot edit it.

Javascript code:

```
var listEditHTML = "\
    <textarea name='edit_text'> Enter a date </textarea>\
";

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var App = { };
    App.default_text = 'Enter a date';

    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).html(listEditHTML);
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<button> edit </button>
```

Also the code was created with JFiddle so here's the fiddle if anyone's interested:
http://jsfiddle.net/wasingej/TT5nw/17/

**note:** I also tried running this code in the W3schools 'tryit' editor and it produced the same results so I doubt that the issue is with my Fiddle.

Comment: Cant u hide the button and show the text area and focus on text area.. I hope u know the methods

Comment: Listen to prash - it's what I would do. Your method does not make sense :)

Comment: It's invalid to put interactive content inside a button.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
        $(this).after(listEditHTML);
        $(this).remove();
});
```

or as @Dan pointed out, use `replaceWith`

The problem is, you're putting the text field *inside* the button (you can see the button-y background in your original fiddle). You want to put the field *after* the button, then remove the button.

Comment: Or just replace it with `$(this).replaceWith(listEditHTML);`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a text area inside the button,

you need to do #

```
$(this).parent().html(listEditHTML);
```

look here

http://jsfiddle.net/SdJrX/

Warning:  **this will replace all the content of the button: if there were chidren inside it they will be lost.**

Comment: Unless parent had no other child than button

Comment: True, but then that is how the question is stated, and how the poster expected it to work.

Comment: I don't think the OP expected all other content in the parent of the button to be replaced by the text area. At least that's not stated in the question. Instead they say they want the button to turn into a text area. You should at least add a warning about the side effects of you solution in case the OP does not know that other content will be replaced, too.

Comment: Mostly people post sample usecase to explain their real case . Inc me. Your answer is good.  But as Dan mentioned , a warning is also needed.